# Edit a textbox within header (first page different)

Tags: vba, ms-word

EDIT: I can make it work in a separate document, but not based on the template documents.

I am trying to edit a textbox within the header of a template-created file within a loop. The textbox name is "Text Box 2." It already has text inside of the box. The goal is replace one of the words ("COUNTRYNAME") with the String CountryName2 (see full sub posted below). Here is the relevant code for actually getting in and editing the textbox:

```
Set tFile = Documents.Add(tPath)
       Selection.InsertFile (cDirPath & "\" & cFile)
       Debug.Print tFile.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Shapes.Range(Array("Text Box 2")).TextFrame.TextRange.Text 'This will print the text within the textbox with DebugPrint but if I try to set it = to something and get rid of Debug.Print (allegedly to edit/add text) nothing happens
```

I can edit the text within the Header using a simple: `tFile.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Text = "Replaced Header Text"`
But it replaces the entire header with that text (I have a number of things on the header already that I do not want to change - just the one and only textbox.

Entire sub: The point of the sub is to open a bunch of files within a directory and copy them into a new template document, then change that template header to match a country name found within the filename.

```
Sub CopyAndPaste()

Dim tPath As String 'template path string
Dim tFile As Document 'template file
Dim cDirPath As String 'copy directory Path
Dim cName As String 'name of copy
Dim CountryName As String ' country name1
Dim CountryName2 As String ' country name2
Dim pDir As String
Dim findTextH As String

findTextH = "COUNTRYNAME"

pDir = "C:\Users\XXX\XXXX\Desktop\Test\Saved\"

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) 'pick the template document path
        .ButtonName = "Pick Template"
        .Title = "Pick the template"
        If .Show <> 0 Then
            tPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'pick the directory with the files path
        ' show the file picker dialog box
        If .Show <> 0 Then
            cDirPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

cFile = Dir(cDirPath & "\" & "*.docx")

Do While cFile <> ""

    cName = GetFilenameFromPath(cFile) 'get the original file name without path
    
        CountryName = Mid(cName, 19)
        CountryName2 = Left(CountryName, Len(CountryName) - 5)

    Set tFile = Documents.Add(tPath)
        Selection.InsertFile (cDirPath & "\" & cFile)
        Debug.Print tFile.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Text
        
        '.Shapes.Range(Array("Text Box 2")).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Testing" ***FOR TESTING&***
        
    tFile.SaveAs2 FileName:=pDir & cName
    tFile.Close
    cFile = Dir
    
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. This was due to a hidden textbox on the second page header which was messing things up. The textbox was filled with white text!!! Ended up figuring it out somehow.